# Measure Page Load Time in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have users on IE 8 who claim that an intranet website loads "slow". We are trying to quantify what constitutes "slow" and I am looking for a tool to count the load time of a page in IE. Firebug provides something similar where it says a page took "3.9 seconds" and breaks it down by component. I looked at the IE Developer Tools, but couldn't find anything similar. The "Profiler" tab is the closest, but it doesn't provide a grand total for time spent loading the page.

Is there any free (preferably Microsoft) tool for determining the load time of a webpage in IE? I know that the load time will vary from PC to PC and based on network load, but I still want to track it.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/05/14/using-httpwatch-to-measure-page-load-times-for-new-and-existing-users/) is a method for IE.